# How do you do superposition to find value of voltage source

Tags: superposition

I know when you are using superposition you have to find the contribution of each independent source. You do this by turning voltage sources to short circuit and current sources to open circuit. then you sum the value of the contributions. This question asks for the voltage of a independent voltage source, would i just consider the contribution of the current source then?

Comment: I think some more information is needed. *"This question asks for ...".* You may have forgotten to add the question.

Comment: Can you show us the example because I don't understand what you want from us?

Comment: Were you given some other information, like the voltage across a certain resistor or the current through a certain branch?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking 'replace each voltage source with a short', think 'turn down all voltage sources to 0 V', and do the same with any current sources. They will still be short or open respectively. It comes to the same thing, but I find it's sometimes easier on my brain if I don't have to remove components, only change their value. Where it can be handy to replace zero volt voltage sources by a wire is if it helps you identify resistors that can be combined in series or parallel.

The solution for all sources at zero is trivial, zero everywhere.

Now turn up each source individually, and solve for that one, with the others set to zero. Now add all the solutions together.